# Are there any free Windows based BluRay players out there?

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray

I have a BluRay drive in my PC, and I'm wondering what the cheapest way to actually get it to play a movie is (I didn't expect this to be trouble). I'm using Windows 7.

I installed CyberLink PowerDVD 8 (I'm currently downloading 10 but it's taking a very, very long time) and I get the below "error" when trying to watch a BluRay movie:

> CyberLink PowerDVD is not able to play the protected content on your digital output device. Please switch to an analog output (VGA, D-Sub) and then try again.

I can't get VLC to play it and my research yields no plugins for VLC to enable it either - unless I'm vastly missing something.

Help!

Answer (score 2):

This may be of help: [How to Get Blu-Ray Support In Windows 7.](http://windows7news.com/2009/10/13/how-to-get-blue-ray-support-in-windows-7/)